# JSONP:Hitting url and parsing the response

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have url which will return response as Content=image|text=hello|.
While hitting the url with AJAX i am getting Cross domain issues.
So i tried searching for jsonp.But unable to do that.I am able to hit the url using script.
But unable to catch the response into string.My final aim is to hit the url and catch the response in some var x.So i want x=Content=image|text=hello| after hitting the url.
I used ajax it works in IE only.

Please try to help/advice to do the same with jsonp.

Comment: That doesn't look like JSON, so you cannot apply JSONP easily. You would need to string-escape it pass a string literal to the JSONP callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you've described from a browser doing without [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/), which would require that the server supplying the response trusts your document's origin, that the user is using a [CORS-enabled browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors), and that if you want to support IE8 and IE9, your code handles using the MS-specific `XDomainRequest` object rather than the standard `XMLHttpRequest` object on those two browsers (other browsers support CORS via `XMLHttpRequest`, including IE10 and up).

If you can get the source of this information to reply with [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) instead, you can do it without CORS. JSONP is a specific format. Here's example of that data in JSONP format:

```
foo({"Content":"image","text":"hello"})
```

...assuming you've called it with a URL like `http://example.com/some/api?callback=foo` (with JSONP, you supply the name of the function — `foo` in the above — in the query string).